# directions for building a jsp as a beginner

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, jsp, web-applications

I have built an application in the google app engine in eclipse and I now need to build a website in which people can interact with the programs results in their web browser. Google-app-engine indicates that I should be building jsp pages.

Now I am knew to web development completely. I have spent the last couple of weeks learning HTML and CSS so that I can understand it from a basic level. However, I do have a couple of questions to clear up:

Could a webpage written in a jsp look as good as one written in a variety of HTML, CSS and javascript files?

Is it a lot more difficult to write a webpage in a jsp?

Would it be better to have the application running on google app engine and then to host the website seperately after being built with HTML,CSS and js?

Comment: A page written in JSP is the same as a page in HTML, CSS. The JSP part of it is the server side processing that you need to interact with your data store etc. At the end what you send to your browser is pure HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all take a look at this http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

A page written in jsp coul look as pretty as a html/css/js because actually the output of a jsp is actually html/css/js. You just control how to prints those elements using special tags.

Write a page is a jsp is in my opinion as difficult as write it in asp.net, php or over technlogies. But there are some alternatives like rails that could make the thing easier.

If you want to explore `javascript only` approaches then take a look at this http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/

Comment: Thanks! I am now integrating my knowledge of HTML and CSS into the tutorials that you linked to.

Comment: you are welcome, please close this question. Read carefully as most examples as you can, and if you have any other question don't hesitate

Answer (score 0):

For creating dynamic HTML you use JSP's. You can also host static HTML pages, without using JSP's.

If you need a very scalable and reliable host, GAE is my personal choice.

To learn to work with JSP's, look for (google) a tutorial or the [GAE java getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps?hl=nl). JSP is part of Java and not a GAE only tool.

Comment: So effectively I could write a static HTML page and name it under a .jsp and it would have the same effect? (I wouldn't of course - I would also use js to create some interaction with the program)

Answer (score 0):

HTML CSS JavaScript: CLIENT SIDE CODE to make the User interface, while 
**JSP :** is to fill results in your interface

JSP, ASP.net, PHP, Python etc. are all server side languages[ they do all the hard work or moves a website], Whereas HTML/CSS/JS are client side languages[their main purpose is interaction with user].

I know JSP, Php, Python, b/w three of these I would say JSP little hard for people who have no knowledge of Java-SE, while PHP, Python can be learned very quickly and easily.

p.s I am also a beginner in Google app engine, I deployed a website their, you can view it http://webenggproject.appspot.com

Comment: Yes I am an intermediate user of Java-EE at the moment. I have managed to build an application that trawls certain parts of the web for certain information and stores it in the datastore. Thanks for the help it has cleared up a lot of the questions I had. Also nice start on the google-app-engine website :) but watch out because when I go to login it has your e-mail address and password!

Comment: both are fake. :) . I hard coded that in website, for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As voscausa said, but no, don't name the pages .jsp. Write it in html, css and javascript, and modify the web.xml file to the name of your start page. Put your web pages in the project war folder, along with your resource folders, etc. Depending on how you wrote your application you should be able to reference it with a jsp url, assuming it's a java servlet, but you'll get more layout options with a jsp page. Save the jsp extensions for pages which have only dynamic layouts.